# cfcollection tags - can create but cannot purge or delete a collection

Tags: solr, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfml, coldfusion-2016

I'm trying to use a simple component to add, purge and delete collections with ColdFusion v 10 (latest update) - when I use ColdFusion administrator I have no problem creating, purging or deleting. When I call the functions to create a collection it works. When I call the function to purge or delete the same collection nothing happens. Any thoughts?

Here are the components:

```
<cffunction name="purgeCollection" access="public" returntype="query" returnFormat="JSON" >
    <cfargument name="collectionName" type="varchar" required="true" >

    <cfindex action="purge" collection="#arguments.collectionName#" status="qStat"  >

    <cfreturn qStat>

</cffunction>

<cffunction name="removeCollection" access="public" returntype="void" >
    <cfargument name="collectionName" type="varchar" required="true" >

    <cfcollection action="delete" collection="#arguments.collectionName#" >

    <cfreturn>

</cffunction>
```

Comment: After upgrading to ColdFusion 2016 the functions work correctly however the path is now ignored and all collections are created and stored in the default collection folder. It seems that the path where I was saving the file wasn't allowing the cf_user I created in windows (running the ColdFusion application service for security purposes) to delete or modify the collections.